# AS3 sortOn issue

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting

Having a problem with a proper secondary array sort operation.

Right now I have

```
sortOn(["score", "timeStamp"], [Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC, Array.NUMERIC]);
```

the goal being to sort on 'score' first, then if items have same score, sort by date or 'timestamp'

It works except that the sort by timestamp is reversed.

The documentation is somewhat vague, at least to me. Can anyone supply the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks
I also tried this and seems to work. Is there something wrong with doing it in one sort like this?

```
sortOn(["score", "timeStamp"], [Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC,Array.DESCENDING| Array.NUMERIC]);
```

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong. As I said, I don't know how exactly you want to sort so you need little tweaking :) I think the problem is if you want to you different sorting options (ascending/descending).

Answer (score 1):

You must do two sorts one after another. I cannot truly understand how you need to sort them, but IF you want to sort on score descending, and on timeStamp (ascending), this works for me:

```
var arr:Array = new Array();
arr.push({score: 11, timeStamp: 21});
arr.push({score: 12, timeStamp: 35});
arr.push({score: 10, timeStamp: 20});
arr.push({score: 11, timeStamp: 22});
arr.push({score: 12, timeStamp: 31});

arr.sortOn(["timeStamp"], [Array.NUMERIC]);
arr.sortOn(["score"], [Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC]);

for (var i:uint = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    trace (arr[i].score, arr[i].timeStamp);
}
```

If you want something else - you could tweak it a little, but that's how it works - two sorts one after another :)